# Matlab textscan with fixed width

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have to read a file like this

```
10001   3          5.0000      30.0         0.0000      25.6         0.0000      10.0
10002   1         25.0000                   0.0000                   4.6887      58.2
10003   5         45.0000      20.0         0.0000                  14.7608          
10004   5         65.0000                   0.0000                   8.8791          
10005   1         85.0000                   0.0000                   6.3128      00.0
```

where the file format like this '%5i%5i%%10.4f%8.1f%10.4f%8.1f%10.4f%8.1f'

I'm using the following code

```
n_xyz_filename = input('\nSelect the file. ', 's');
n_xyz_file = fopen(n_xyz_filename, 'r');
n_xyz = textscan(n_xyz_file, '%5i%5i%10.4f%8.1f%10.4f%8.1f%10.4f%8.1f');
fclose(n_xyz_file);
```

But I keep on getting the following error

> ??? Error using ==> textscan Badly formed format string.

I really can't get it!

**EDIT**

As the answer said, the right code is:

```
n_xyz_filename = input('\nSelect the file. ', 's');
n_xyz_file = fopen(n_xyz_filename, 'r');
n_xyz = textscan(n_xyz_file, '%5d%5d%10.4f%8.1f%10.4f%8.1f%10.4f%8.1f');
fclose(n_xyz_file);
```

with the "d" (stand for decimal) instead of "i"

Comment: Are you sure the file is fixed width and not tab delimited? Maybe try `dlmread` with `\t` as the delimeter?

Comment: I'm sure is fixed: I've just generated it as a string.

Comment: @Dan: it's not `tab`-formatted unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the format specifier `i`, which is not recognized by `textscan`. In case you wanted to indicate an integer, you should've used `d`. The correct syntax is therefore:

```
n_xyz = textscan(n_xyz_file, '%5d%5d%10.4f%8.1f%10.4f%8.1f%10.4f%8.1f');
```

Comment: Yeah! That almost done it!
But now I have another problem: the matrix n_xyz now is displayed as following
`n_xyz = [3498x1 int32]    [3498x1 int32]    [3498x1 double]    [3498x1 double]    [3498x1 double]    [3498x1 double]    [3498x1 double]    [3497x1 double]`

and each components are show as vector

Comment: @MicheleRedaelli There is no problem: It seems that your file contains 3498 lines (and obviously 8 columns, like specified in the format string). Each cell therefore contains all the extracting values from the corresponding column. To access each cell, use curly braces (`{}`), for instance the values of the second column are `n_xyz{2}`...

Comment: thanks a lot
You made my day!
I hate professor asking you to do something w/o explaining the basic!